# How to restrict printing of an attribute of a class rather than the class itself in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a dataclass as follows:

```
@dataclass
class DBCreds:
    db_name: str
    password: str
    description: str
    db_type: str
```

Here I want to restrict anyone else who is using my code or any newcomer to just come in and print the password (Even though the name password is self explanatory that it shouldn't be logged in production environments).
I want:

```
a = DBCreds("testDB","testDB","DB for testing","postgres")
print(a.password)
```

this print should give the following out put
`Passwords cannot be printed` instead of printing the value.

I have tried to add `__repr__` method to the class like this:

```
@dataclass
class DBCreds:
    db_name: str
    password: str
    description: str
    db_type: str

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Passwords cannot be printed"
```

With this I was available to avoid someone doing `print(a)` But still someone would be able to print the password with `print(a.password)`
Really appreciate if you would help me with this. Thanks in advance.